# Relationship filter in whereHas callback with Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent, wherehas

Given the following models

**Conversation**: id, user_id,

**Message**: id, conversation_id, author_id, created_at

I wanted to query all conversations who have messages between `$start` and `$end`, so i did this:

```
$filterMessages = function($query) use ($start, $end) {
    $query->whereBetween("created_at", [$start, $end]);
};

$convs = Conversation::whereHas("messages", $filterMessages)
->with(["messages"  => $filterMessages]);
```

And it works. Now i need to add a condition: the message.user_id must match his conversation's user_id (both in whereHas and with). So i changed my callback to this:

```
$filterMessages = function($query) use ($start, $end) {
    $query->whereBetween("created_at", [$start, $end]);
    $query->where("conversations.user_id", "author_id");
};
```

But it does not work. How could i do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this

`Conversation Model` define relationship

```
public function userMessages()
{
   return $this->hasMany(Message::class, 'author_id', 'user_id'); //your relationship based on data structure
}
```

```
$convs = Conversation::whereHas('userMessages',function($query) use ($start, $end) {
                           $query->whereBetween("created_at", [$start, $end]);
                       })
                      ->with("userMessages")
                      ->get();
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question, as i said i need "the message.user_id must match his conversation's user_id". The date query already works. Thanks

Comment: Then you can define a relationship with `Conversation` check my latest post

Comment: it's a good idea, however the userMessages relationship ignore the conversation_id field, so it also returns other conversations messages :(

Comment: `message.user_id==conversation.user_id` or `message.author_id==conversation.user_id` can you specified? so i can update my post

Comment: it's `author_id`!

Comment: Ok i managed to do it using the `topclaudy/compoships` package:
`return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Chat\Message', ['author_id', 'conversation_id'], ['user_id', 'id']);`

Comment: after update relationship. above example is working or not?

Comment: No it did not, because it's ignoring the first relationship rule i need (conversation.id -> messages.conversation_id). Thank you for your time tho